# Vertex factor type-I seesaw

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, beyond-the-standard-model

Consider the following interaction term:
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal{L}_\text{int} = y_{ij}\bar{\ell}_{iL}\tilde{\eta}N_{jR} + \text{h.c.}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
   \ell_{iL} = \begin{pmatrix}\nu_{iL}\\ e_{iL}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is the standard $\text{SU}(2)_L$-doublet of left-handed leptons ($i=1,2,3$), $\eta$ is an (inner) $\text{SU}(2)_L$-doublet:
\begin{equation}
   \eta = \begin{pmatrix}\eta^{+}\\ \eta^0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\eta^{+}\\ (\eta_R + i\eta_I)/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix},\quad \tilde{\eta} = i\sigma^2\eta^\ast = \begin{pmatrix}{\eta^0}^\ast\\ -\eta^{-}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}(\eta_R - i\eta_I)/\sqrt{2}\\ -\eta^{-}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $N_j$ are right-handed fermions (RH neutrinos; $j=1,2,3$) and singlet of $\text{SU}(2)_L$. The Yukawa matrix $y_{ij}$ could be non-diagonal but real. Due to a mixing that occurs in the scalar sector of the theory, the charged scalars $\eta^{\pm}$ are decomposed in terms of the following charged mass eigenstates:
\begin{equation}
   \eta^{\pm} = H^{\pm}_1c_\theta - H^{\pm}_2s_\theta
\end{equation}
where $c_\theta = \cos\theta$ and $s_\theta = \sin\theta$. The mass eigenstates of the theory are $\{e^{\pm}_i, \nu_j, N_k, H^{\pm}_1, H^{\pm}_2, \eta_R, \eta_I\}$. When expanding the interaction term in terms of these mass eigenstates, we find:
\begin{align}
   \mathcal{L}_\text{int} &= -y_{ij}c_\theta\bar{N}_{jR}e_{iL}H^{+}_1 - y_{ij}c_\theta\bar{e}_{iL}N_{jR}H^{-}_1 + y_{ij}s_\theta\bar{N}_{jR}e_{iL}H^{+}_2 + y_{ij}s_\theta\bar{e}_{iL}N_{jR}H^{-}_2 \\
   &\quad - iy_{ij}\bar{\nu}_{iL}N_{jR}\eta_I + y_{ij}\bar{\nu}_{iL}N_{jR}\eta_R + iy_{ij}\bar{N}_{jR}\nu_{iL}\eta_I + y_{ij}\bar{N}_{jR}\nu_{iL}\eta_R
\end{align}
I have two questions:

> What are the vertex factors for the following diagrams?

[image]

Following standard rules, I think they should be:
\begin{align}
   \text{vertex factor (a)} &= -iy_{ij}c_\theta P_R \\
   \text{vertex factor (b)} &= iy_{ij}s_\theta P_R \\
   \text{vertex factor (c)} &= -iy_{ij}c_\theta P_L \\
   \text{vertex factor (d)} &= iy_{ij}c_\theta P_L
\end{align}
where $P_{L,R}$ are the left and right projectors. From here, my other question is:

> What would be the correct vertex factor to use in the vertex (encircled in red) of the following diagram?

[image]